# How to generate chunked request in Fiddler?

Tags: request, fiddler, chunked, transfer-encoding

I need to test a server and to send a chunked request from Fiddler. I need to send something very simple, for example 'a' character as a content.

There is a Request Builder tab where I can set Transfer-Encoding: chunked header, but how do I specify Request Body?

Comment: Do you need have a dynamic response, or can you simply record and replay some previous traffic that has the chunking you require?

Comment: @PaulGrime I just do not have any chunked request examples and no previous traffic.

Comment: I'm a Java person and Fiddler uses JScript.NET, but I think you can call out to standard .NET classes. So maybe one of the class like this could help - https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/caf3bc3ea26af4027cee81fa99a50d69f810ed63/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs. Otherwise, I'd use Java and Apache HTTPComponents to perform the chunking for me in a separate process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like very simple, just need to add 2 CR LF after 0:

```
5<CR><LF>
aaaaa<CR><LF>
0<CR><LF><CR><LF>
```